# Backbone.js router - route with splat also calls route with no splat

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a backbone.js router set up with some routes as follows :

```
routes : {
  'a-route' : 'goToRoute',
  'a-route/*splat' : 'goToRoute'
}

goToRoute : function(splat){
if(!splat) {
  // do this
} else {
  // do that with splat
}
```

When I do a

```
router.navigate('a-route', {trigger : true});
```

everything works just fine. But when I do

```
router.navigate('a-route/more', {trigger : true});
```

the router is firing twice : first with the splat equal to 'undefined', and then a second time with the splat equal to 'more'.

If I comment out the route 'a-route' : 'goToRoute', then everything works as it should with router.navigate('a-route/more') ... but I need both routes - with and without the splat.

According to the docs I think I have this set up correctly, any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have already? just redirect from `splat === undefined` to wherever you want to go from there.

Comment: there is a different layout depending on whether there splat === 'more' or splat === 'undefined'. Currently, calling router.navigate('a-route/more', {trigger:true}) is triggering both routes, and so it is rendering both layouts on the same page

Comment: i meant, remove the `a-route: goToRoute` and in `goToRoute` do `if (splat === undefined) {justARoute(); } else { splatRoute(splat); }`

Comment: if i do it this way, a call to router.navigate('a-route') doesn't find a match - the page is not rendered

Comment: what about `'a-route': 'goToRouteWithoutSplat'` and `'a-route/*splat': goToRouteWithSplat`. The splat = undefined is caused by your routing working completely fine, but when you go to the route 'a-route', there is not parameter relayed to the route function

Comment: I may have the wrong setup, but works for me http://jsfiddle.net/7u2Bg/1/ with or without pushstate

Comment: thanks @nikoshr that's the right setup... perhaps the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use *, you must use : in your case.

```
routes : {
  'a-route' : 'goToRoute',
  'a-route/:splat' : 'goToRoute'
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think there is a difference between a parameter and a splat if there is only one item after the backslash. I think a splat just lets you put everything after the backslash into a single variable, whereas parameters each represent one component.

Comment: If you try in the way that I paste you it will enter only one time. The problem with splat is that is some kind of wildcard so your router has two valid entries.

Comment: the other possibility is that you have a call to router.navigate('a-route', {trigger : true}); inside the function that is called on 'a-route/*splat'